# If $g(x)=\int_1 ^3f(x+t)dt$ what will be the value of $g'(0)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be continuous function such that $f(1)=-5, f(3)=11.$ If $g(x)=\int_1 ^3f(x+t)dt$,

> Then what will be the value of $g'(0)$

I don't understand how to solve this, Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

Say $\int_1^3 f(x+t)dt = F(x+3)-F(x+1)$ by Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.
So $g(x)=F(x+3)-F(x+1)$ and $g'(x)=F'(x+3)-F'(x+1)$ or, $g'(x)=f(x+3)-f(x+1)$

Answer (score 2):

This is solved using the fundamental theorem of calculus.
$$
g(x)= F(x+3)-F(x+1), \,\text{where} \,F'= f
$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that substitution $t=u-x$ leads to: $$g(x)=\int^{3+x}_{1+x}f(u)du=F(3+x)-F(1+x)$$ where $F$ is the antiderivative of $f$.

Differentating both sides we find: $$g'(x)=f(3+x)-f(1+x)$$
and consequently:$$g'(0)=f(3)-f(1)$$

Answer (score 0):

Change variables to get $$g(x)=\int_{1+x}^{3+x} f(u)\,du = \int_0^{3+x}f(u)\,du - \int_0^{1+x}f(u)\,du$$ then use the Fundamental Theorem for each term.